# Can contact stresses become independent of the rolling velocity in a viscoelastic rolling-contact?

Tags: elasticity, viscosity, contact-mechanics

In nonlinear viscoelastic rolling contact problems (assuming a viscoelastic wheel rolling/slipping with zero slip angle on a rigid body with friction), is it possible that the contact stresses (contact pressure and the tangential stresses) become independent of the angular velocity of the wheel? If yes, then under what circumstances?